# iOS 13 new pageSheet/formSheet navigationBar Height

Tags: ios, xcode

As we can see from image below, the new presentation style of iOS 13 built with XCode 11 made navigation bar have a different height (56 height) compared to the one presented 'fullscreen' (44 height).

The problem here is my app is using a custom written navigation bar and the height of the custom navigation bar is calculated with
`UINavigationController.navigationBar.frame.height` which give us 44 height as default. We are trying to adopt to the new presentation style, but I could not think of a work-around. I think I'm also not covered situation such as large title navigation bar and compact navigation bar. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Credits to : https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e

[image]
2) Image with navigationBar Height of 56 in presentationStyle .pageSheet

[image]
3) Image with navigationBar Height of 44 in presentationStyle .fullScreen

Comment: You haven't explained how that navigation bar is configured. But basically if you're in a navigation controller, you should not try to change the navigation bar's height.

Comment: @matt Sorry for the unclear explanation but to follow up here, the navigation bar is not customised at all, it is still the native navigationBar from navigationController, what we did is we added a custom imageView inside the navigationBar by extending it. We are not trying to change the navigation bar's height but to get the corresponding navigation bar height for our custom imageView. The navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet or .automatic. It made all presented navigationctrl's navigationBar have a default size of 56 height.

Comment: Alternatively, you can "opt-out" of this new mode and keep the old one (fullscreen).

Comment: Sorry but it's still unclear to me what the problem is. What is "added a custom imageView inside the navigationBar"? It's perfectly fine to give a navigation bar an image. I don't understand what you think is wrong with the screen shot you showed.

Comment: @matt Hi again, I've edited 2 more image samples in the main thread. Image 2 and 3 is the comparison of navigationBar height difference. What I wanted to do here is to programmatically or by using code to get the 56 height so it can be more flexible in the future.

Comment: @NicolasMiari We are trying to adopt to it since it's the new 'standard' and we also hope to get an answer as if we are forced to use it.

Comment: I'm still unclear what you're trying to do, but it appears you are trying to read some sort of meaning into the navigation bar height. That seems a mistake. The problem is that the height the navigation bar gives you as its height is not the height at which it is actually drawn. On an iPhone X, it is drawn extended upward a lot. On an iPhone 8, it is drawn extended upward a little (20 points). In large title mode, or when there's a search bar in it, it is drawn extended down a lot. The _apparent_ height of a navigation bar is _never_ identical to the height it gives, in portrait.

Comment: @BrandonWong Same problem! Did you solve?

Comment: @Giorgio Yes, I did fixed it with a temporary solution by using KVO, I add an observer to the navigationBar's layer's bound. And observe the height changes then apply the height to my custom navigation bar. I've been thinking of another solution instead of using KVO as it's going to be deprecated one day.

Comment: @BrandonWong I fixed it with a temporary solution, too. I used this [workaround](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/378841#378841).

Comment: @Giorgio Cool, but that seemed like a native bug behaviour.. I haven't really meet that problem but my situation in this case is different because I'm implementing an imageview on top of the navigationbar~ and I wish the image to be resize the same as navigationbar despite future updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is seems to be a bug in iOS, I've used [this workaround](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/378841#378841), but I call it in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear` because the latter applied the fix only  after the view controller animation finished.

```
override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {  
     // ... 
     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {  
          navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()  
     }  
}
```